# how to set a PopupWindow showing on another PopupWindow

Tags: java, android, popupwindow

there are two PopupWindows in my app and They intersected. now I want to manage a PopupWindow showing on another PopupWindow, it means the Z Axis. any ideas for this?
you can see the following pictures.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: As far as I know the latest popup will always draw over the old one. `PopupWindow` does have a `setElevation` method. But it was added in API 21.

Comment: I have used setElevation(), but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can try calling `show()` on the previous popup after you call `show()` on your new popup.

Comment: Why you want to show popup over popup? Can you specify the scenario?

Comment: If I call show() on the previous popup after call show() on my new popup, I should dismiss it then call show(), but I will see it dismiss then show. it is stagy.

Answer (score 0):

There is first PopupWindow,and click TextView on this PopupWindow then show the second PopupWindow.

```
PopupWindow mPop,mPop2;

    /**
     * show first popupWindow
     */
    private void popupWindow(final View vi) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.pop, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        //click show second one
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupWindow2(vi);
            }
        });
        if (null == mPop) {
            mPop = new PopupWindow(view);
        }
        mPop.setHeight(294);
        mPop.setWidth(200);
        mPop.setFocusable(true);
        mPop.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        mPop.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        mPop.showAtLocation(vi, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 22,
                22);
        mPop.update();

    }

/**
    * show second popupWindow
    */
    private void popupWindow2(View v) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.pop2, null);
        if (null == mPop2) {
            mPop2 = new PopupWindow(view);
        }
        mPop2.setHeight(294);
        mPop2.setWidth(200);
        mPop2.setFocusable(true);
        mPop2.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        mPop2.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        mPop2.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER, 42,
                42);
        mPop2.update();

    }
```

And solve this problem.hava a try.
[image: sample]

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is the normal order for popupwindow, but if I want to let the first one over the second one, should I recall the show() of  the first one? I don't want to do this, I only want to know whether there is any ideas for handle one popupwindow show over another one.